# add or change the language of zabbiz executed in docker

Tags: zabbix

someone could guide me to add the spanish language in zabbix using docker. I was investigating and the examples that come out are in Apache and it's different.

my docker-compose file is this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zabbix-db:
    image: monitoringartist/zabbix-db-mariadb
    volumes:
      - zabbix-db-storage:/var/lib/mysql
      - backups:/backups
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=zabbix
      - MARIADB_PASS=my_password
  zabbix-server:
    image: monitoringartist/dockbix-xxl:latest
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "10051:10051"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    links:
      - zabbix-db:zabbix.db
    environment:
      - ZS_DBHost=zabbix.db
      - ZS_DBUser=zabbix
      - ZS_DBPassword=my_password
      - PHP_date_timezone=UTC
volumes:
  zabbix-db-storage:
    driver: local
  backups:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what you are asking. Could you please try to rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the wiki](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Translating_Zabbix#Translating_frontend) the spanish language menu entry is hidden because the translation is incomplete.

> If a translation drops below 75% completion, it is hidden from the
>   language selection. Note that it is not removed, just not displayed in
>   the default dropdown. A translation is added to the dropdown when it
>   reaches 100% completion.